# Why are my Gridview elements overlapping the Toolbar in the android?

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview, android-framelayout

I have been using FrameLayout as parent view to display Gridview elements where I want to display them below Toolbar but it's not getting displayed below Toolbar but overlapping the Toolbar like this.[image]

Below is code of my xml layout file fragment_user.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Add the Toolbar -->
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
        android:title="Lingo"
        android:titleTextColor="@color/new_design_darker_shade">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
            android:id="@+id/searchView"
            android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFFF"
            android:queryHint="Search..."
            android:iconifiedByDefault="false" />
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <!-- NestedScrollView to contain the GridView and make it scrollable -->
    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <!-- Your GridView -->
        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/mainSpecimens"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="?android:actionBarSize"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:horizontalSpacing="6dp"
            android:numColumns="3"
            android:verticalSpacing="6dp" />
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The NestedScrollview has it's height set to match parent. So it will fill out the whole screen.

Replace the top level FrameLayout with a ConstraintLayout and place the toolbar and NestedScrollview below each other.

Comment: Can you provided edited code? I am not very comfortable with ConstraintLayout

Answer (score 0):

`FrameLayout` drawn its child views in a stack.

`LinearLayout` drawn its child views vertically/horizontally.

`ConstraintLayout` drawn its child views with constraints to each other or to `ConstraintLayout` itself.

It's best that you have a basic understanding of these layouts, because they're currently the most common layouts in uses. You can build any kind of UIs with only just `LinearLayout` and `FrameLayout` or `ConstraintLayout`.

Update your xml:

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

...

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">
...
```

Setting `android:layout_height="0dp"` and `android:layout_weight="1"` will make the child view to take all the available space.